# implement git diff for two folders within same branch

Tags: git, git-diff

I want to do git diff for two different folders located at different location within a same branch. how can i achieve this. can i store it in file with proper visual UI. git diff should be using only git.

Comment: Looks like `diff` is enough for your need

Comment: If you want to use graphical diff tool, I recommend using `meld`. Using meld, you `meld dir1 dir2`

Comment: @Ôrel i have tried this diff. but if i want to store it in file with graphical , how can i achieve this?

Comment: @GMaster i will try this.

Comment: @GMaster how can i use this meld command. i am using gitbash on windows.

Comment: Try `git diff <commit1>:<folder1> <commit2>:<folder2>`. `commit1` and `commit2` can be the same one, `HEAD` for example. If you want to compare `foo/` and `bar/` on the same branch `master`, `git diff master:foo master:bar`.

Answer (score 0):

> `git diff` should be using only git

Not exactly: with the `--no-index`, you can use it with any path

```
git diff --no-index some/path other/path >> some_filename
```

And this works in a git bash or CMD on Windows.

Comment: some/path other/path >> some_filename??

can elaborate some/path other/path and some_filename.

Now diff is too lengthy. i want to store it in file. how can i store it?

Comment: @gt06 repalce them by your path. >> some_filename redirect the output to a filename of your choosing